# VisualDiagnostics.VisualTreeChanged event without attached debugger?

Tags: wpf

In WPF there is an event VisualDiagnostics.VisualTreeChanged that triggers every time a new element is added to the visual tree (anywhere). The problem is that this only works when a debugger is attached to the process. Is there any way of getting around this limitation? Any other similar event that works without a debugger? Can I fake an attached debugger?

My goal is to get a list of all elements of certain types (Button, TextBox, ComboBox etc) in a Window, including those generated from a template. I need this to set certain automation properties in runtime.

One possibility is to use the Window.LayoutUpdated event, but this triggers very often and most of the times without any new elements added. I would have to iterate through the entire visual tree on every layout update to find new elements and I don't think that will be very efficient. I would certainly prefer a more direct method.

But the VisualDiagnostics.VisualTreeChanged event is not ideal either since the element in the event-args does not yet contain any of it's children. A button would for instance not even have it's own text-content yet. If there were a third option where I could get hold of the entire element-fragment of all new elements as they are added that would be great.

(Have tried overriding OnVisualChildrenChanged as well but this does not catch new descendant elements, only children it seem)